# I am fetching data from a JSON file and displaying the list in my view(directory.php).But it's showing some error: order:notArray

Tags: angularjs, json

> If I am doing it by defining an array, it's all working fine.But the
>   issue occurs only when I try to fetch JSON data.

---

### Below is my code for a file directory.php which I am later including with ng-view in my main index file using routing:

---

> Order By Name
>         Order By Belt

```
<div class="content">
    <button ng-click = "order = 'name' " >Order By Name</button>
    <button ng-click = "order = 'belt' " >Order By Belt</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model = "search" placeholder="Search for a ninja here...">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "ninja in ninjas |orderBy: order | filter: search" ng-show = "ninja.available">
            <img ng-src = "{{ ninja.thumb }}" style="margin: -12px 10px 0 0; float: left; width: 55px" ng-show = "ninja.thumb" />
            <h3>{{ ninja.name }} - {{ ninja.rate | currency}}</h3>
            <div class="remove"  ng-click = "removeNinja(ninja)">×</div>
            <span class="belt" style="background: {{ ninja.belt  }}">{{ ninja.belt }} belt</span>   <hr><hr>        
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit = "addNinja()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ninja name here..." ng-model = "newninja.name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ninja belt here..." ng-model = "newninja.belt">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ninja rate here..." ng-model = "newninja.rate">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Ninja">
    </form>
</div>
```

### And in the module, I am using this code.The last section using $http.get()... is the concern here:

---

```
let myModule = angular.module('myModule',['ngRoute']);

myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{
            templateUrl:'views/home.php'
        })
        .when('/directory',{
            templateUrl:'views/directory.php',
            controller:'MyController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/home'
        });

}]);

myModule.controller('MyController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.addNinja = function() {

        $scope.ninjas.push({

            name: $scope.newninja.name,
            belt: $scope.newninja.belt,
            rate: parseInt($scope.newninja.rate),
            available: true
        });

        $scope.ninja.name = "";
        $scope.ninja.belt = "";
        $scope.ninja.rate = "";

    }

    $scope.message = "Here is the list of some ninjas below";

    $scope.removeNinja = function(ninja) {

        let removedNinja = $scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
        $scope.ninjas.splice(removedNinja,1);
    }


    $http.get('data/ninjas.json')
        .then(function(data) {
                $scope.ninjas = data;
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            }
        );

}]);
```

### Below is the JSON file which contains the data:

```
[
    {
    "name": "Yoshi",
    "belt": "green",
    "rate": 50,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/Yoshi.png"
    },

    {
    "name": "Lee",
    "belt": "black",
    "rate": 100,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/Lee.png"
    },

    {
    "name": "Law",
    "belt": "yellow",
    "rate": 1000,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/Law.png"
    },

    {
    "name": "Jin",
    "belt": "orange",
    "rate": 300,
    "available": false,
    "thumb": "content/img/Jin.png"
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you receive a JSON object you must convert in into Object by angular.fromJson() method

try in this way

```
$http.get('data/ninjas.json')
        .then(function(data) {
                $scope.ninjas = angular.fromJson(data);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Doesn't work that way either.Same error Error:[orderBy:notarray]

Comment: Got the answer now...
Have to write data.data instead of just data...like 

$http.get('data/ninjas.json') .then(function(data) { $scope.ninjas = angular.fromJson(data.data); }, function(error) { console.log(error); } );